# How to remove curly braces and double quotes from array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

At this Project i use Angular 8 and typescript.

I have an array that displays emails upon type input or upon csv upload.
once input of some emails is done, there is a button to send invitations to these mails.

To load  the emails into the array i use this code (this.emails is the identifier for the array which is set up as `emails: string[] = [];` and called via ngfor loop in the html)

```
 onFileInput($event: any): void {
    const files = $event.target.files as File;

    this.csvService
      .parse(files[0], { header: false })
      .pipe()
      .subscribe((result: Array<any>) => {
        this.emails = result;
      });
  }
```

This works fine as it adds the emails to the array. But when i use the invite function, it identifies the email in the array as {"email@test.de"} while it should actually be just email@test.de.

The wierd part is that the array actually just shows email@test.de . And when one enters the email via input, the invite function properly identifies is as email@test.de

So the problem seems to be that what gets loaded to the array with the code above is actually not a plain string

the array logs a csv imported emails as ​ `email: Array [ "email@test.de" ]` while it logs a type input mail as `email: "email@test.de"` (as it should be)

So is there a way to modify the function to remove the curly braces and double quotes before it enters the array?

Comment: May I see `console.log(result)`?

Comment: It might seem that your parser resolves a JSON format. You should, as mentioned, console.log() result variable and then take a decision. Maybe try in your ngFor {{value[0]}}

Comment: the array logs a csv imported emails as
​
email: Array [ "email@test.de" ]  while it logs a type input mail as email: "email@test.de" . i updated the decription
​

Comment: can you share code how you displayed them  in html?

Comment: @LogicBlower   <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let email of emails"
        [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(email)"
      >
        {{ email }}

        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>

Answer (score 1):

you can use regExpr to remove the {} and []

```
this.csvService
  .parse(files[0], { header: false })
  .pipe(
     map((emails:any[])=>
         emails.map((email:string)=>email.match(/([\[{]).+([\]}])/)?
                      email.match(/([\[{]).+([\]}])/)[0].slice(1,-1):
                      email
       )
     )
  )
```